# Submit weekly time sheets online. (Drupal?)

Tags: forms, drupal, lamp

first time post here.  I have been lurking for a while, and realized you guys knows your stuff.  Maybe you can help.  I am trying to make a simple online application for employees to login and submit their hours worked for the week.  When you login, it should have the current week displayed, (EG 1/16/11 - 1/22/11) then under the date have 7 forms. One for each day of the week.  So under Monday, they can type how many hours worked.  After submitted it should goto a database and be viewable by an admin, and be archived so we can go back and see their working history.  I am pretty flexible when it comes to coding.  Though I don't claim to be a code prodigy by any means, I am pretty fluent with WordPress (LAMP Stack) and starting to get into Drupal.  I have been playing with a few drupal modules with little luck.

If anyone has some ideas on how I could do this, please let me know!  If you know of another open source application that can do this, please let me know. I am not sold 100% on drupal.

The server this will be hosted on is a VPS running CentOS on the standard LAMP stack.

Thank You,

PJ

Comment: There are so many readily available time tracking SaaS solutions out there, why would you ever even imagine rolling your own?

Comment: They are all so complex for what we need.  Do you have any suggestions? I spent all last night googling with no luck on anything that is what we need. If you have some suggestions though, i'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I agree with Brian that there are already enough (mostly awful) timesheet apps out there. However, if you are interested in learning Drupal, this could be a good starter project. You might also consider lurking around http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: IMHO [Freckle](http://letsfreckle.com/) is ridiculously easy to use. I've also used [FreshBooks](http://www.freshbooks.com/), however that includes a lot of other features besides time tracking that you may or may not be interested in.

Comment: Thanks DOK and Brian! I will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1) Create a node with CCK module as per your need.

2) User Form API or you can directly use Create node form with giving right permissions to your user w.r.t. role

3) Create a view with your created node.

4) Assign a page to view

5) Give access to restricted role

6) Assign user to restricted role, role which will allow user to see the timesheet.

And you are done.